# asp.net usercontrols and nested tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

how can we create UserControl that is composed of nested tag like this :

```
    <uc:MyPanel>
       <header>
           title here...
       </header>

       <content>
           content here...
       </content>
    </uc:MyPanel>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: i have a panel with compelceted layout so to avoid copy/past the code of the panel, i decided to create custom control, wich will have sub tags to hold the title and the content of the panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i found, for people how want to do the same things

popup.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
  CodeBehind="Popup.ascx.cs" Inherits="Dynamic.Popup" %>
<div style="width: 400px; padding: 1px; border: 1px solid #BED6F8;
  background-color: #FFFFFF; position: absolute" runat="server" id="panel">
   <div style="padding: 1px 1px 2px 5px; height: 18px; border: 1px solid #BED6F8; cursor: move;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white,#BED6F8); background-color: #BED6F8"
   runat="server" id="titlePanel">

   <asp:Literal ID="ltTitre" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

   <div style="position: absolute; right: 3px; top: 3px; z-index: 100; cursor: pointer">
       <img src="close.png" alt="fermer" onclick="$find('popUpPanel').hide();" />
   </div>
```

Popup.ascx.cs

```
 [ParseChildren(true)]
  public partial class Popup : System.Web.UI.UserControl
  {
   [TemplateContainer(typeof(MessageContainer))]
   [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
   public ITemplate MessageTemplate { get; set; } 

   public string Text { get; set; }

  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ltTitre.Text = Text;

     if (MessageTemplate != null)
     {
        var i = new MessageContainer();
        MessageTemplate.InstantiateIn(i);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(i);
     }           
   }

     public class MessageContainer : Control, INamingContainer{ }
 }
```

the use of usercontrols

```
<uc:Popup ID="p" runat="server" Text="Titre1">
    <MessageTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
       Test
    </MessageTemplate>
</uc:Popup>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you're looking for, you'll need to create a custom server control that can interprit nested tags. It will require a *lot* of work.

It looks like you're trying to create a layout for your site. If that is what you're trying to do you would be better to using master pages, and creating content placeholders for the header, footer, content, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is Master pages with a `Content Place holder`. e.g.

```
 <div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                My ASP.NET Application
            </h1>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
```

Have a look at this [ASP.NET Master Pages Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials)

Comment: i'm trying to create custom UserControl witch i can reuse over pages

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are after as I was trying to find a way of doing this myself in the past. I had some complicated HTML which generated a box with a header. Rather than copying the HTML, each time I needed this box, I was hoping I could specify a header/content/whateverelse tags nested inside.

I can't find my original question, but I remember there not really being the answer I was looking for.

In the end I believe I was told to look into [Custom Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx) rather than user controls.

I hope this helps

Comment: i found somthing on the msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/36574bf6%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that uses INamingContainer, and ITemplate but can't understand the logic behind it